# Perfect matching in a vertex-transitive hypergraph

Tags: hypergraph, perfect-matchings, co.combinatorics

In connection with [this MO problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92568/perfect-matchings-in-certain-classes-of-hypergraphs), I wonder whether the hypergraph in
question was actually vertex-transitive. And so, as a natural variation (and,
perhaps, a refinement):

> If the vertex set of a vertex-transitive hypergraph $H$ can be partitioned as
>   $V_1\cup\cdots\cup V_r$, so that every edge of $H$ contains exactly one
>   vertex from each of the partite sets $V_i$, what reasonable conditions
>   guarantee that $H$ possesses a perfect matching?

(As an example of a reasonable condition: $H$ is non-empty. An unreasonable
condition would be that $H$ is (almost) complete in the sense that it
contains the edge $\{v_1,\ldots, v_r\}$ for (almost) any $v_1\in V_1,\ldots,
v_r\in V_r$.)

---

The case $r=2$ is easy: we are then looking at vertex-transitive bipartite
graphs, and every such graph has a perfect matching by Hall's marriage
theorem (provided it is non-empty). Indeed, it suffices that the graph be
regular. For $r=3$ vertex-transitivity is insufficient as shows, for instance,
the following construction. Let $G$ be a finite abelian group of order
divisible by $2$, but not by $4$. Let $V_1,V_2,V_3$ be (disjoint) copies of
$G$, and consider the hypergraph $H$ on the vertex set $V_1\cup V_2\cup V_3$
whose edges are all triples $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ with $v_1+v_2+v_3=0$. If a
perfect matching in $H$ existed, then the sum of all elements of $G$,
multiplied by $3$, would be equal to $0$, which is not the case.

Comment: I am not sure about vertex-transitive graphs, but this link may be useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall-type_theorems_for_hypergraphs

Answer (score 2):

This answer is not for vertex transitive hypergraphs (I have not noticed that condition)!

No simple necessary and sufficient condition can exists as 3DM is NP-complete:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-dimensional_matching

Of course, if you are only looking for a sufficient condition, one can come up with several, eg. see:
http://arxiv.org/abs/1101.5830 where it is proved by Imdadullah Khan that
"A perfect matching in a 3-uniform hypergraph on $n=3k$ vertices is a subset of $\frac{n}{3}$ disjoint edges. We prove that if $H$ is a 3-uniform hypergraph on $n=3k$ vertices such that every vertex belongs to at least ${n-1\choose 2} - {2n/3\choose 2}+1$ edges then $H$ contains a perfect matching. We give a construction to show that this result is best possible."

Comment: Thanks! I was unaware of the three-dimensional matching problem. As to the second part of your answer, the degree assumptions are exactly what I had in mind mentioning "unreasonable conditions"...

Comment: And, by the way: does the problems remain NP-complete if we confine to vertex-transitive hypergraphs?

Comment: One more remark: there is no necessary and sufficient condition which is easy to check computationally. However, there still can possibly exist a "logically simple" and useful condition!

Comment: Oh, I have no noticed you ask for vertex transitive... I don't know anything about that for hypergraphs. For non-empty graphs with an even number of vertices you must have a perfect matching in this case, this follows from the Gallai-Edmonds Decomposition. Do you have a counterexample for hypergraphs?

Comment: I appended an answer at the end of my original post.

Comment: Indeed. I think instead of inefficient you wanted to write insufficient. Now I wonder if 2-vertex-transitivity, or in general r-1-vertex-transitivity is sufficient.

Comment: Sorry for my illiteracy, but what is "$2$-vertex-transitivity"?

Comment: Now you caught me! I guess I meant that picking any 2 vertices from any 2 classes, you can map them into any 2 other vertices of the respective classes with an automorphism, but your construction is a good counterexample even for this, so just forget my comment...